# How to retrieve connectionStrings from Server Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in, server-explorer

I would like to write an extension to Visual Studio, which will enable me to generate a model for specified table.

I have used the following code to add MyCommand item into context menu of table in server explorer:

```
Commands2 commands = (Commands2)_applicationObject.Commands;
CommandBar menuBarCommandBar = ((CommandBars)_applicationObject.CommandBars)["Object Node"];

Command command = commands.AddNamedCommand2(_addInInstance, "MyCommand", "MyCommand", 
    "Executes the command for MyCommand", true, 59, ref contextGUIDS,
    (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported + (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled,
    (int)vsCommandStyle.vsCommandStylePictAndText, vsCommandControlType.vsCommandControlTypeButton);
if ((command != null) && (menuBarCommandBar != null))
{
        command.AddControl(menuBarCommandBar, 1);
}
```

To get the name of the selected Table item:

```
string fileName = "Dafault.cs";
var serverExplorer = _applicationObject.ToolWindows.GetToolWindow("Server Explorer") as UIHierarchy;
if (serverExplorer != null)
{
    dynamic item = ((object[])serverExplorer.SelectedItems)[0];
    fileName = string.Format("{0}.cs", item.Name);
}

//...
// Generate model based on table from database 
//...

_applicationObject.ItemOperations.NewFile("General\\Text File", fileName, Constants.vsViewKindCode);
```

How can I get information about the database connection?

Answer (score 0):

Brad Larson, why my question was deleted?

Found the solution.
Used [this](https://retina.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Main/Source/Retina.Designer/Dsl/ServerExplorerSupport/ServerExplorerHelper.cs)

```
public static IDbConnection GetConnection(DSRefNavigator navigator, out string type)
        {
            type = null;
            try
            {
                if (navigator != null)
                {
                    IVsDataConnectionsService dataConnectionsService =
                        (IVsDataConnectionsService) Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(IVsDataConnectionsService));
                    string itemName = navigator.GetConnectionName();
```

`if (itemName != null)
                {
                    int iConn; // = dataConnectionsService.GetConnectionIndex(itemName);
                    DataViewHierarchyAccessor dataViewHierarchy = null;

                    for(iConn = 0; iConn < dataConnectionsService.Count; iConn++)
                    {
                        DataViewHierarchyAccessor hierarchyAccessor =
                            new DataViewHierarchyAccessor((IVsUIHierarchy) dataConnectionsService.GetConnectionHierarchy(iConn));
                        try
                        {
                            if (hierarchyAccessor.Connection.DisplayConnectionString == itemName)
                            {
                                dataViewHierarchy = hierarchyAccessor;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                        }
                    }
                    if (dataViewHierarchy != null)
                    {
                        DataConnection connection = dataViewHierarchy.Connection;
                        if (connection != null && connection.ConnectionSupport.ProviderObject != null)
                        {
                            type = connection.ConnectionSupport.ProviderObject.GetType().FullName;
                            return (IDbConnection) connection.ConnectionSupport.ProviderObject;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        return null;
    }`

Comment: _why my question was deleted_ because you posted it as an answer ;-)

Comment: Thanks. It's clear but I've found no way to post comment for question (it only possible for answers). Must be I confused something.

Comment: the way to go is to ask your own question, possibly with a link to this (showing an effort of search - as you did - is always a good sign) You can both answer and comment your own questions, so might try to attract the former poster with an @username in a comment to your question. Never tried, though. Cheers, and welcome to SO :-)

Comment: Thanks! In both cases users will be attracted - I prefer the simpler way=)

Comment: hmm ... what's the _simpler way_? As you experienced, "answers" that are questions (or anything else not actually answering) will be deleted rather soon after being posted ;-)

Comment: If the user is informed in both cases, both cases can be used. Otherwise it's just my nonsense.